# Python 3.3.4. How to swap values within an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Okay, so I took my GCSE computer science exam today and I couldn't complete the last question as I felt it was too much of a struggle. I don't remember the exact wording of the question, but I do remember what it asked. So , there was an array of 6 people and the user could then input how many places that every player would move.I would then have to create an algorithm which would update the array of where each person was in the array after each movement. The problem was that these people were sitting around a table and their seats were numbered from 1-6 so if they all moved 2 spaces , person six would then be in seat 2 making them second in the array of course. Because this question was bugging me so much I came home and saw if I could create an algorithm using python.

Here is what I came up with :

```
array = ["susan", "mary", "david", "tom", "richard", "mark"]

places_moved = int(input("How many places would you like to move?"))

for i in range (0,6):
    if i + places_moved > 5:
        array[i] = (array[i + places_moved - 6])
    print (array[i])
else:
    array[i] = (array[i + places_moved])
        print (array[i])
```

As you can see, this doesn't actually update the arrays at all since it was just my first approach to see if I could get it to print out what the new array values would be. However, I failed to succeed in even this as the code only changes what array is being printed and doesn't change the position of the array's data.

It's kind of hard to explain, so I'm doubtful for an answer, but if I actually did make any sense, I'd very much appreciate if anyone could give me a working algorithm for the question given. Thanks guys/gals!

Comment: Questions like these are normally to probe if you are familiar with using modulo. When it's something that goes in a circle by integral indices like this, chances are modulo is a good solution. :)

Comment: So.... during this change of seats - does every person goes `x` seats forward, or does the user have to define how much seats will *every* single persone move to?

Comment: @konart The user defines the how many seats everyone will move, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. The only 'trick' is to use the modulo operator to limit the seats to 0...5. Also, the formula adds 6 to avoid generating negative seat numbers.

```
def main():
    array = ["susan", "mary", "david", "tom", "richard", "mark"]

    places_moved = int(input("How many places would you like to move?\n" + \
                             "(positive is to the right) "))

    new_list = []
    for seat in range(6):
        new_list.append(array[(seat + 6 - places_moved) % 6])

    print new_list

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(Just an observation: array is not an array but a list in this case)
After this, you can assign the new_list to array, if you like:

```
array = copy.deepcopy(new_list)
```

And, just for the purists who don't want to use an extra variable, (or even modulo!) :)

```
def main():
    array = ["susan", "mary", "david", "tom", "richard", "mark"]

    places_moved = int(input("How many places would you like to move?\n" + \
                             "(positive is to the right) "))

    if places_moved >= 0:
        for move in range(places_moved):
            array = [array[-1]] + array[0:-1]
    else:
        for move in range(abs(places_moved)):
            array = array[1:] + [array[0]]

    print array

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to swap exactly two elements in a list:

```
seq[i], seq[j] = seq[j], seq[i]
```

if you want to "rotate" a list so that each element is some distance away from its starting point:

```
seq = [seq[(i + distance_to_move) % len(seq)] for i in range(len(seq))]
```

Comment: Exactly! Note the use of modulo :)

Comment: can't we just `new_arr = array[-n:] + array[:n]` where `n` is number of seats they moved? Positive `n` - to the right, negative - to the left

Comment: @konart, perhaps, although I suspect that approach may fail for large values of `n`. For instance, `seq = range(10); seq[-100:] + seq[:100]` gives an array with more than 10 values.

Comment: @Kevin In which case you could set `n = n % 6` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

@jcoppens: Python works perfect with negative indices. e.g. array[-1] gives the last element.

```
new_list.append(array[(seat + places_moved) % len(array)])
```

should just be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo, or remainder operator `%` to keep the new indices within the bounds of the array's length and a list comprehension to update the array:

```
array = ["susan", "mary", "david", "tom", "richard", "mark"]

places_moved = int(input("How many places would you like to move?"))
length = len(array)

array = [array[(i+places_moved) % length] for i, elem in enumerate(array)]
print(array)
```